# sticky-top full-width dropdown on hover navbar

Tags: css, hover, navbar, dropdown, sticky

I m a newbie on bootstrap techniques and i m trying to compine two different styles in a navbar. 
the first is about sticky navbar and the second Full-width dropdown navbar, both found on an educational website.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_mega_menu_responsive
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky

i ve tried several changes with no result and i dont have much knowledge.
any help would be much appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: Need an example of the code you are trying to write.

Comment: It's the same of the links I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you correctly - you need to combine sticky menu and dropdown. You don't need javascript to do that. Use **position: sticky;** and **top: 0;** no **.navbar**

**UPDATED**

Added **.dropdown-content** fix of height and inner scroll in **@media**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;  
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown button.dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .header {
  background: red;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  /* fix the dropdown height on small screens*/
  .dropdown-content {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 46px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
      </div>   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 1</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 2</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 3</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is a problem when i open it in small screens. dropdown column category 3 doesnt show. i tried changing widths but didnt manage to solve it. any ideas please?

Comment: Just updated an answer. If everything is correct - you can mark a question as a right solution, for the community to know that your request is competed.

Comment: any ideas about how i can make this navbar collapse in small screens? i just place some more dropdown buttons and i really need this

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {  .dropdown-content {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 46px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
  } } This part of code. Try in on your computer or editor. it might help. You can see it in my updated version of an ansver. It makes dropdown part scrollable on screens less than 600 px widh.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/focusstyle/vngyL176/ try to make a result window less than 600 px and scroll the page, hover dropdown and scroll the dropdown. I suggest you not to use big header and use menu on without position sticky on small screens.

Comment: i m thinking the same but i really liked it. i hope i ll find a solution to make it more responsive somehow